# Nodejs Express giving 404 error

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an express application

below is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsforce = require('jsforce');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var oauth = require('./routes/oauth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/oauth/auth', oauth);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

//salesforce

/* OAuth callback from SF, pass received auth code and get access token */
app.get('/auth/salesforce/callback', function(req, res) {
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({oauth2: oauth2});
    var code = req.query.code;
    conn.authorize(code, function(err, userInfo) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

        console.log('Access Token: ' + conn.accessToken);
        console.log('Instance URL: ' + conn.instanceUrl);
        console.log('User ID: ' + userInfo.id);
        console.log('Org ID: ' + userInfo.organizationId);

        req.session.accessToken = conn.accessToken;
        req.session.instanceUrl = conn.instanceUrl;
        res.redirect('/accounts');
    });
});


app.get('/accounts', function(req, res) {
    // if auth has not been set, redirect to index
    if (!req.session.accessToken || !req.session.instanceUrl) { res.redirect('/'); }

    var query = 'SELECT id, name FROM account LIMIT 10';
    // open connection with client's stored OAuth details
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
        instanceUrl: req.session.instanceUrl
    });

    conn.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        res.render('accounts', {title: "Accounts List", accounts: result.records});
    });
});
// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

and this is my routes/oauth.js

```
var express = require('express');
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var router = express.Router();

var oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
    clientId: "3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrCvXcC3DFadDjpWkzxie8m4kCKhZ8ioGXx90ciGmuV1pW6joTi1giQNZTy.7ZvWkBvc_kmW",
    clientSecret: "3184414314550851555",
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/salesforce/callback'
});


/* SF OAuth request, redirect to SF login */
router.get('/oauth/auth', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({scope: 'api id web'}));

});

module.exports = router;
```

other routes are working but when I go to http://localhost:3000/oauth/auth

It is throwing 404

```
Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
    at C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\app.js:33:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (C:\Users\rajarshi.das\nodemysales\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12
```

can anyone help me to sort out the error.

I am new on express .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I can able to solve it .

It was a simple mistake

```
/* SF OAuth request, redirect to SF login */
router.get('/oauth/auth', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({scope: 'api id web'}));

});
```

it should be refer only `router.get('/'...`

```
/* SF OAuth request, redirect to SF login */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({scope: 'api id web'}));

});
```

as it is already in use

`app.use('/oauth/auth', oauth);` in app.js